# Is there ever a case for a SQL cache?

Tags: sql, architecture, nosql, system

The most common caches today seem to be Redis, Memcached, and Cassandra. These all fall under the key-value, in-memory, NoSQL family of data stores.

Knowing this, along with knowing that caches as well as NoSQL are usually preferred with a small amount of data, begs the question: when designing any system, is there ever a strong case for having a SQL cache? Would the benefits ever go beyond extremely minimal?

Comment: Engines do caching all the time automatically behind the scenes, to reduce I/O as much as possible. That's why there are "hot" and "cold" blocks, and their planning costs differ quite a bit.

Comment: What do you mean by SQL cache, more exactly? SQL is a query language, Cassandra has CQL which is similar to SQL. I think you need to add more clarity to the aspect of `SQL cache`